# When exactly does light get refracted?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

Short question: When does a light ray know it has to bend/be refracted? I know it happens at the interface of two media. But when is there an interface of two media? When there is a single hydrogen atom and 500 km away a helium atom?

[image: img]

I've seen [Why exactly does a material reflect/absorb/refract light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/519753/why-exactly-does-a-material-reflect-absorb-refract-light) but I think, either there or here, there would be some more input helpful.

Comment: The idea of refraction at interfaces cannot be used right down at the molecular or atomic levels. "Refraction" in the conventional sense does not happen when there are just a few atoms.

Comment: makes sense, guess on the atomic level, there is only scattering?

Comment: Scattering is certainly one of the microscopic phenomena that occurs. As usual, scattering is not as simple as high school level textbooks make it seem. I am however not experienced enough at physics to answer your question in any more detail. I think Hecht's book on optics would be a great place to learn more if you're interested.

Comment: I'm a particle physicist and for me, it's rather hard/uncommon to think at macroscopic levels. But yes, scattering is very complicated but optics and other stuff as well :) Wow, just googled your book advice and it shows me another book, for ~5 k ^^

Comment: btw, thanks for the advice, may I ask why exactly this one?

Comment: Woah if you meant $5k, that sounds insane. Here's a link https://www.amazon.com/Optics-4th-Eugene-Hecht/dp/0805385665/ref=sr_1_3?crid=2H5FJ6XDX2S55&dchild=1&keywords=hecht+optics&qid=1625064064&sprefix=hecht+%2Caps%2C136&sr=8-3 . I got a copy when I was traveling for around 10USD. I am a photonics researcher and I think this book is an overall great entry to optics. Of course, I also thought that you might be a high school student so you might already be familiar with most of the stuff in the book. Most college libraries have a copy of this book.